# How to schedule/trigger spark jobs in Cloudera?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, cloudera

Currently our project is on MR and we use Oozie to orchestrate our MR Jobs. Now we are moving to Spark, and would like to know the recommended ways to schedule/trigger Spark Jobs on the CDH cluster. Note that CDH Oozie does not support Spark2 Jobs. So please give an alternative for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I looked, Hue had a Spark option in the Worlflow editor. If Cloudera didn't support that, I'm not sure why it'd be there...

CDH Oozie does support plain shell scripts, though, but you need to be sure all NodeManagers will have `spark-submit` command available on the local server.

If that doesn't work, it also supports Java actions for running a JAR, so you could write your Spark scripts all starting with a main method that loads up any configuration from there

Comment: how do we view the spark UI for jobs trigger like so? how to does monitoring etc work with these?

Comment: I can't remember, but the Spark UI should be the same... No matter how you run the program (shell or Oozie), it's still being executed within YARN. With Oozie, I would probably use client deploy mode so that Oozie can collect the driver logs, and from the driver logs, it prints out the Spark UI address. For monitoring, JMX or log collection just over all YARN containers would be a good start, but Oozie collects job status information

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you submit the spark job from the shell, like:
`spark-submit <script_path> <arguments_list>`
it gets submitted to the CDH cluster. Immediately you will be able to see the spark jobs and its progress in the Hue.This is how we trigger the spark jobs.

Further, to orchestrate a series of jobs, you can use a shell script wrapper around it. Or, you can use a cron job to trigger in timing.

Comment: but how do we schedule them, how do I create a workflow that has multiple Spark jobs in it? Is there an alternative to the spark submit?

Comment: As I have mentioned in the answer, you can schedule them using a crontab job.